# How to handle Payment gateway when internet connection is disconnected

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

For example in paypal when completed the payment, the response is going to response.php at that time if our server goes down. how to handle this situation and what need to be done.

In other payment gateway also how to handle the situation when our server goes down or net is got disconnect while the response is receiving.

Comment: try to format question in right way so that one can answer it?
Where is response.php ?
Be specific about which payment gateway.

Some of the payment gateway like instamojo have webhook that send response to sever ,if it fails it will resend after some time.

Comment: Thank you.But i am asking about any payment gateway.for example payumoney.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand from your question and comment you want to implement payumoney as payment gateway.

So both payumoney and instamojo use concept of webhook.

for webhook 
https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/development/general.html

There is no direct way to handle that situation.Moreover now days server failure is a rare case ,if are using some standard web server.

There is a indirect way for that use

Transaction Status Api
https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/apireference.html#operation/getPaymentResponseUsingPOST

Call transaction status Api , to get status of payment

**Note:** If your user lost their net connectivity  after payment ,it will not effect any thing.As after payment is done ,situation is handle by GateWay server and your server.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply.Can you explain above with example? I am not understood.According to you i should call getPaymentResponse api ?